# Error on run SQLPackage.exe /a:script

Tags: visual-studio, database-project, sqlpackage

I'm trying to automate the database deploy process an I'm using the `SqlPackage.exe`.
I have some database deployment process working with this `exe` but recently I've been facing an problem to a new database.

When I try to run:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DAC\bin\sqlpackage.exe" /a:Script /op:p_dbprm003.sql /sf:c:\p_dbprm003.dacpac /TargetServerName:servernamexyzw /TargetDatabaseName:p_dbprm003 /Profile:c:\p_dbprm003.publish.xml

I get the message:

> The reference to the element with the name '[xxx_user ]' could not be resolved.
>   More than one element with this name exists. To resolve the error, you must add
>   one or more disambiguators.

I really don't know what does it means.

I have a user `[xxx_user]` and a schema `[xxx_user]` with the same name. Do you think that it could be an possible cause of the error?

Comment: I do think the name being equal can be the reason for the error. Is it possible to change one of the object names? If it is, I think it's the easier of the alternatives.

Comment: Can you use the actual project? If so, I'd try opening that in SSDT and trying to publish it that way - you might be able to narrow it down a bit more. Also, you have seem to have a space in the name above. If that's the case, you'll need to fix the package/dacpac anyway.

Comment: Hey Pete, So, I am able to deploy via Visual Studio. The database project compile successfuly and I'm able to deploy it also. Actually I did not understand what you said about fix the package/dacpac.. What you mean???? by the way Thank you for help since now...

Answer (score 0):

You must set the path variable of **SqlPackage.exe** as a system variable.It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading this old post, I ran into this same issue today (Sql server 2017) and found a solution. Notice the error message from the original post:

> The reference to the element with the name '[xxx_user ]' could not be
> resolved. More than one element with this name exists. To resolve the
> error, you must add one or more disambiguators.

Notice that '[xxx_user ]' has a trailing space at the end. Remove the trailing space(s) from your users/schemas, export your .dacpac and the issue should now be resolved.